# How to use builder place holder function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new to JavaScript `bind()` and I want to build a placeholder function.  The original callback function is like:

```
function fn(event, data1, data2){
    console.log(data1, data2);
}
```

I tried to build the placeholder function like:

```
var fn_bind = fn.bind(null, undefined, undefined, "data2");
```

later I want to call `fn_bind("event", "data1")` to print

```
"data1", "data2"
```

But it keeps giving me

> undeinfed, "data2"

Any idea?

Comment: You cannot bind later parameters and keep earlier parameters assignable. `fn.bind(null, undefined, undefined, "data2");` means that the first and second parameter are bound to the value `undefined`. `fn_bind("event", "data1")` will actually pass the 4th and 5th argument.

Comment: No, `bind` only allows you to bind the initial parameters. Passing `undefined` doesn't mean future arguments will replace that value. You'll have to use a custom `bind` function that allows you to do such.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks, I get it now.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, I get it now

Comment: @Kuan: you might want to search the web with the terms "partial application with placeholder"